# SwiftUI Picker selection not updated unless value shown in view (using Enum for selection)

Tags: swiftui, enums, picker

```
import SwiftUI

enum TestEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case firstValue = "First Value"
    case secondValue = "Second Value"
    case thirdValue = "Third Value"
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var testEnumSelection = TestEnum.allCases.first!
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Test Enum Selection", selection: $testEnumSelection) {
                ForEach(TestEnum.allCases, id: \.self) { testEnum in
                    Text(testEnum.rawValue)
                }
            }
            //Text("Enum Selection: \(testEnumSelection.rawValue)") Enum value not updated if this line is not inlcuded
            Button("Show Sheet", action: {
                isShowingSheet = true
            })
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            Text(testEnumSelection.rawValue)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use an enum value selected from a picker in a sheet view but the value from the picker is not being updated for the sheet.  The value does get updated if I show the picker selection on screen elsewhere like in a Text object but I don't want to do that.

Could someone explain to me why I need to show the enum selection for it to be updated for the sheet and how to get around doing this?

[image: Selection not displayed elsewhere - Does not work]

[image: Selection displayed elsewhere (not what I want to do) - Does work]

Comment: You need to add a tag `Text(testEnum.rawValue).tag(testEnum)`

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sheet content is created once, so it is not updated when state in parent is updated.

The possible solution is to separate sheet content into standalone view and use binding - bound variable will update view internals.

Here is a modified part (tested with Xcode 13.2 / macOS 12.1)

```
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            SheetContent(value: $testEnumSelection)  // << here !!
        }
    }
}

struct SheetContent: View {
    @Binding var value: TestEnum

    var body: some View {
        Text(value.rawValue)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the sheet view to be a different view for each enum option. How would I hand this case?

Comment: You can handle this inside `SheetContent.body` using `switch`, but it is a different question, out of the topic.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the Binding?  I don't need to enum value in the view, I just need it to know which view to make.